# I want to click on the image to go to another page

Tags: flutter

```
  IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset(
          'images/Da.png',
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          onPressed:() {},
        )),
```

I want to click on the image to go to another page.

This code doesn't work. Why?

Comment: //This code is not work .  WHY? 

//I want to click on the image to go to another page. 

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB6zf.png

//This is my image .

Comment: You not implement your code in onPressed

Comment: If you have additional information to add to your question, please edit your question instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `Navigator.push` inside IconButton onPressed.

```
 IconButton(
            icon: Image.asset(
              'images/Da.png',
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You were using `onPressed` inside `Image.asset` which doesn't support this property, put that in `IconButton` instead. Here is the complete solution:

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2()));
  },
  icon: Image.asset(
    'images/Da.png',
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 IconButton(
            icon: Image.asset(
              'images/Da.png',
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnotherPage()));
            },
          ),
```

You can use Named Roots and other such things to write an effective flutter code.

[Here is the simple article demonstrating page routing](https://medium.com/@petehouston/navigate-between-screens-in-flutter-8c4c21084e73)